# Facebook Graph and PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been working at this for a few hours, but the poor documentation is of no help.

All I want to do is grab the data that exists at https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/ as an example, and I cant even do that.

I'm using the latest php API from facebook.

This is my code, which returns nothing:

```
<?php

require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '254752073152',
  'secret' => '904270b68a2cc3d54485323652da4d14',
  'cookie' => true,
));


$coke = $facebook->api('/cocacola');


echo '<pre>';
print_r($coke);
echo '</pre>';
```

Any idea?

Comment: well, first... i wouldn't actually put your key up. not enough rep or i would remove it myself.

what is the output of `print_r($coke);` ?

Comment: Not my key, its a public one posted by facebook for their examples. Doesn't work with my keys either.

Output is nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I can't comment, but that doesn't look like a valid API key (not long enough). The `'appId'` should be your **API key** not your Application ID.

Comment: No, the new facebook PHP API requires your Application ID, not your API Key. See the documentation: 



<?php

require './facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR APP ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR API SECRET',
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));

Comment: Not true.. look at the facebook constructor:
 
`/**
   * Initialize a Facebook Application.
   *
   * The configuration:
   * - appId: the application API key
   * - secret: the application secret
   * - cookie: (optional) boolean true to enable cookie support
   * - domain: (optional) domain for the cookie
   *
   * @param Array $config the application configuration
   */
  public function __construct($config) {`

I have no idea why they would start calling it appID.. confusing I know.

(Sorry, that's hard to read, see it here: http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php)

Comment: I figured it out, no help from the the documentation. I needed to call both the API key and the APP ID. Thanks :)

Comment: where did you call the app id?

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the tutorial http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/ to fully understand step by step of graph api and php sdk.

Comment: thats actually where I ended up getting code that works haha. No help from facebook :|

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out efpa, you can get a whole user's stream using(customizable with CSS);

```
$userHome = $myapp->userHome();

foreach($userHome as $uhf) {

  $myapp->userStreamTmp($uhf);
}
```

or getting user information;

```
$myapp->userInfo('name');
// or
$myapp->userInfo('gender');
// or
$myapp->userInfo('id');
```

you can check out the documentation http://labs.gurron.com/projects.php?proj=efpa&pg=docs

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the contents directly using file_get_contents and parse them using json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just trying to get the info from the cocacola page in an array, I'd avoid using the Facebook library - its overly complex, and just make a simple request like:

```
<?php
$contents=file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/');
$json=json_decode($contents,true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($json);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```